# WooCommere: Display Out Of Stock badge for Product In Backorder

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my WooCommere shop, when my product is in backorder the Sales badge still shows up on my product. I would like to replace the Sales badge with the Out Of Stock label.

I have this code so far:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'new_badge', 3 );         
    
function new_badge() {
  global $product;
  if ( $product->is_on_backorder(1) ) {
    echo '<span class="out-of-stock-badge" data-shape="type-3">' . esc_html__( 'Out Of Stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
   }
}
```

This code only add the span with the out-of-stock badge over the existing Sales badge, which provokes an overlap.

Is there a way to remove directly the Sales badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the filter 'woocommerce_sale_flash' to remove default sale flash badge.

try out this code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'new_badge', 3 );         

function new_badge() {
   global $product;
 if ( $product->is_on_backorder(1) ) {
   add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', function (){return false;});
    echo '<span class="out-of-stock-badge" data-shape="type-3">' . esc_html__( 'Out Of Stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
  }
 }
```